# How are emoji/canvas/text rendered on browsers like Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Does anyone know the code, pipeline or the way these browsers render emoji, canvas, text, etc on their browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows first update your Firefox and for Chrome browser, use this extension
=>  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromoji-emojis-for-googl/negakbijaemdgbhklopmghphgaeadmpo/